# Multer file is not removed if upload is canceled

Tags: node.js, storage, multer

Is there Any Function in **Multer** To Remove uploaded part of the File from the server if The Request gets Cancelled

Answer (score 3):

This has been a bug in multer for a very long time. See this issue on github: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/259, where various workarounds are listed in the conversation.

In our project we're currently using the fork "kyleerik/multer#kyleerik-patch-1" which is mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/259#issuecomment-594064102) and it has been working fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is my approach worked for me

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    const fileName =
      file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, fileName);    
    req.on('aborted', () => {
      const fullFilePath = path.join('uploads', 'videos', fileName);
      file.stream.on('end', () => {
        fs.unlink(fullFilePath, (err) => {
          console.log(fullFilePath);
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
        });
      });
      file.stream.emit('end');
    })
  }
```